# Filtering a Touch.FrameReported IObservable using arbitrary boolean condition that changes over time

Tags: system.reactive, observable

I've been playing around with the Reactive Extensions (RX) in Windows Phone 7 and am very close to a working solution but got caught up on one small detail. I am trying to process the raw touch events using [Touch.FrameReported](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/14/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-2.aspx) and `Observable.FromEvent` (a bit of an educational quest to learn the Touch API and RX better), but I only want to process the events under certain conditions. For example I may want to filter the subscription to the touch down and touch up events only when a specific page is selected in a pivot control, but it could be any arbitrary condition that changes back and forth between true and false. Since the condition is a value that changes over time it feels like it should be another observable that gets merged with the touch event stream, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that.

Instead I have a semi-working solution using the `TakeWhile` and `SkipUntil` extensions for IObservable. I have a stream that receives all the touch events for the whole app (`oTouchApp`), a second stream that only takes items while my filtering condition is true (`oTouchPage`), and then two other streams that filter the touches into touch down (`oTouchDown`) and touch up (`oTouchDown`) actions. All of these streams are of type `IObservable<IEvent<TouchFrameEventArgs>>`, so they can easily be merged and compared to create custom gestures. The problem is that I can't get the the oTouchPage stream to restart once the filter condition changes from true to false. I'd have to manually recreate the stream, where as I would prefer that it somehow toggles itself between on and off.

Here is the code I have so far. Any help on how to filter a stream using a boolean value (like an on/off switch) would be greatly appreciated.

```
var oTouchApp = Observable.FromEvent<TouchFrameEventHandler, TouchFrameEventArgs>(x => new TouchFrameEventHandler(x), ev => Touch.FrameReported += ev, ev => Touch.FrameReported -= ev);
//This stops working after TestCondition goes from True to False
var oTouchPage = oTouchApp.SkipWhile((x) => TestCondition == False).TakeWhile((x) => TestCondition == True);
var oTouchDown = from t in oTouchPage
                 let primarypoint = t.EventArgs.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(this)
                 where primarypoint.Action == TouchAction.Up
                 select t;
var oTouchUp = from t in oTouchPage
               let primarypoint = t.EventArgs.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(this)
               where primarypoint.Action == TouchAction.Down
               select t;
//Code for testing
var sub1 = oTouchPage.Subscribe(x =>{Debug.WriteLine("TouchPage");});
var sub2 = oTouchDown.Subscribe(x =>{Debug.WriteLine("TouchDown");});
var sub3 = oTouchUp.Subscribe(x =>{Debug.WriteLine("TouchUp");});
```

**UPDATE:**
Turns out all I needed was to add a simple where clause to the oTouchPage stream: `var oTouchPage = oTouchApp.Where((x) => TestCondition == True);`
 It may not be the best solution, since the TestCondition is evaluated each time an item is produced, but it works well and is easy to read. If the test condition was based on events or some other condition that was easy to convert into an IObservable, then I think the Window or SelectMany approaches mentioned below might be better, but then you may have to deal with a "Stream of streams". I'm fighting that right now in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841635/how-to-use-the-new-bufferwithtimeorcount-in-rx-that-returns-iobservableiobservab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TakeWhile` triggers completion when the predicate returns false, at which point everything is torn down.

You have two choices:

The simplest solution is to use `Repeat` to start the whole process again:

```
var oTouchPage = oTouchApp
    .SkipWhile((x) => TestCondition == false)
    .TakeWhile((x) => TestCondition == true)
    .Repeat();
```

The other solution would be to track the situation using `SelectMany` to trigger the start of each "round" of listening (this is very similar to the "drag-drop" WPF Rx Example):

```
// Think of Subject like an observable variable
// This can just be an IObservable<bool> if the triggers actually come from elsewhere
Subject<bool> testConditionValues = new Subject<bool>();

var startTrigger = testConditionValues
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Where(v => v == true);

var endTrigger = testConditionValues
    .Where(v => v == false);

var values = from start in startTrigger
             from touch in touchEvents.TakeUntil(endTrigger)
             select touch;

// Start listening
testConditionValues.OnNext(true);

// Stop listening
testConditionValues.OnNext(false);
```

Comment: Thanks! Subject<bool> works great for testing (I was using Observable.Timer :-P) and adding .Repeat() works like a charm. The whole idea of using RX is to make the code easy to read, so I like your first suggestion the best. Still think there is a better way though... maybe using the new Window operator.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Richard Szalays answer you could also look into the `Window` operator (although I think his second solution is probably the right one). You have windows of time that you'd like to receive touch events.

```
private void SetupStream()
{
    Subject<bool> testConditionValues = new Subject<bool>();

    var startTrigger = testConditionValues.DistinctUntilChanged()
         .Where(v => v == true);

    var endTrigger = testConditionValues
         .Where(v => v == false);

    touchEvents.Window(startTrigger, _ => endTrigger)
        .Subscribe(HandleNewWindow);

    // Open window
    testConditionValues.OnNext(true);

    // Close window
    testConditionValues.OnNext(false);

}

public void HandleNewWindow(IObservable<IEvent<EventArgs>> events)
{
    events.Subscribe(mousEvent => Trace.WriteLine(mousEvent));
}
```

Comment: The Window operator looks like exactly what I need, but I am a bit confused about it's usage. It returns an IObservable of IObservables, where I just want a single stream that only produces when TestCondition == True. Is there a way to merge the "stream of sequential streams" into one stream that can be used in oTouchDown/oTouchUp? Also is there anywhere I can find more info or examples for the Window operator? All I can find is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2010/12/25/rx-christmas-release-2010-introducing-join-and-groupjoin-operators-and-more.aspx

Comment: Found a great video from Channel 9 that talks about the Window operator. Doesn't have any real examples, but helps to conceptualize it. Starts around 30mins, but the whole video is good to watch: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Programming-Streams-of-Coincidence-with-Join-and-GroupJoin-for-Rx

Comment: @Greg Bray - If you just want one window to be open at a time (the last one) you can use a Switch operator which will close the previous window and pipe the new one and give you back just an IObservable<IEvent<EventArgs>> (see edit).

Comment: @Greg Bray - For the record I still recommend one of Rich's examples. You only really need to start listening for the events when your condition is true and stop when its false. With the Window operator you are always listening for events and then filtering them out.

Comment: @Greg Bray - Again removed Switch as it won't work for subsequent windows as the subscription will complete at the closing of the first Window